# wordpress advance custom field plugin showing broken image?

Tags: wordpress

I am using [wordpress acf plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/) to show some custom images with their description and some text. So first I just made the [acf plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/) fileds like this and assigned the page to the home page with the conditional tags `Location-> Rules-> Page->is equal to-> Home`
now when I made my `content-page.php` to show the image code like this

```
<?php
if( get_field('image') ):
    ?><img src="<?php the_field('image'); ?>" alt="" /><?php
endif;
?>
```

I am getting only a broken image. The firebug is showing image source like this
Kindly help me to solve this. I have already wasted one day behind it. So any help and suggestions will be really appreciable. Thanks

Here is the screen shot for my custom fields setup

[image]

Here is the firebug html code which is showing the image source

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Had this problem too.  This is what I came up with that works:

```
<?php if (get_field('staff_photo')) { 
    $imgarray = get_field( 'staff_photo' );
?>
    <img src="<?php echo $imgarray['url'] ; ?>" alt="" class="staff-photo" />
<?php } ?>
```

So, what I did was put get_field('field_name') array into a variable, then took a WAG that the key was 'url', which it was.  Seems like the ACF people need to update their documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Hah!  Discovered another way -- this way you can pick a size:

```
<?php
if ( get_field('staff_photo') ) { 
   $imgarray = get_field( 'staff_photo' );
   $size = "thumbnail"; // (thumbnail, medium, large, full or custom size)
   echo wp_get_attachment_image( $imgarray['id'], $size );
}
?>
```

For wp_get_attachemnt_image to work, you have to extract the image id, for which the key is, ta-da! 'id'.

Comment: I'd still like to know what the problem is. While both these answers work, it's frustrating that `the_field('field_name');` doesn't work in this case.